# Update table for all entries from select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my scenario, i select all the entries from a table where the condition is true, put it into a vector and use an update statement through a loop, passing the vector's values. It works.

```
SELECT * FROM MAP AS A WHERE EXISTS  
(SELECT (X, Y) FROM MAP AS B WHERE B.X = A.X + 1 AND B.Y = A.Y ) AND EXISTS     
(SELECT (X, Y) FROM MAP AS C WHERE C.X = A.X - 1 AND C.Y = A.Y ) ;

for...
UPDATE MAP SET VAL = 2 WHERE X = ? AND Y = ?; 
...
```

But i wanted to try and use a single statement to complete this objective, while we can update a table using a select statement, in my scenario there are 2 keys that need to checked before selecting a record, so i'm not able to put a where condition for x or y together.

```
UPDATE MAP SET USED = 1 WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM MAP AS A WHERE EXISTS  
(SELECT (X, Y) FROM MAP AS B WHERE B.X = A.X + 1 AND B.Y = A.Y ) AND EXISTS     
(SELECT (X, Y) FROM MAP AS C WHERE C.X = A.X - 1 AND C.Y = A.Y ) );
```

When i put a where exists condition like above, it updates all the entries. How do i update the table in one query ?

Comment: `SELECT (X, Y) ...` is not valid SQL.

Comment: Yes, i replaced * with (X, Y) to give the statement some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your subquery is that it does not refer to the table (`MAP`) in the UPDATE statement.

Just drop the `MAP AS A` subquery and refer to `MAP` directly (`UPDATE` does not allow table aliases):

```
UPDATE MAP
SET USED = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MAP AS B WHERE B.X = MAP.X + 1 AND B.Y = MAP.Y)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MAP AS C WHERE C.X = MAP.X - 1 AND C.Y = MAP.Y)
```

Comment: Is there any difference between using 1 or X, Y in those select statements ?

Comment: EXISTS checks only for the existence of some record(s), not what's in them.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've verified the subquery is returning the rows you want to update, your update should then look something like this:

```
UPDATE MAP SET USED = 1 
WHERE (X,Y) IN (
SELECT X, Y FROM MAP AS A WHERE EXISTS  
(SELECT X, Y FROM MAP AS B WHERE B.X = A.X + 1 AND B.Y = A.Y ) AND EXISTS     
(SELECT X, Y FROM MAP AS C WHERE C.X = A.X - 1 AND C.Y = A.Y ) );
```

Comment: I tried this code in SQlite Manager and it shows the following error message "near ",": syntax error".

Comment: You're right - looks like sqllite doesn't support the tuple syntax. It doesn't support joins for update either. Let me see if there is another way.